# speech recognition system using VB.Net or JAVA

Tags: java, vb.net

I would like to develop an application something called "speech recognition" or" voice unlocking"system. which should be useful for windows systems..It should store a particular voice.and should compare it with other voices.If same allow him/her to access something. otherwise deny access.So now my question is "Which platform is easy to make it and what are the parameters i should take. ? Please help me out.I wanna do it as my mini project

Comment: That would not be a mini project...
Read more about artificial neural networks and AI and you will get what I mean.

Comment: Do a proper research before embarking on such complex projects. Some things seem easy, but aren't.